# How to delete one character before and after character #?

Tags: c#

How to delete 1 string before and after character #

For Example:
I have string: ABC#DEF
and I want to result: ABEF

Comment: Use string.IndexOf() and string.Substring()

Comment: `string.Join("", str.Split('#').Select(s => s.Substring(0, s.Length - 1)));`

Comment: What if the string is `"#abc"`, the result is `"bc"` ? What if the string is `"#"` or `"##"` ? What if the string is `"123###123"`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use regular expression to split by one char before and after `#`.

```
String.Join("", System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Split("ABC#DEF", @".#."))
```

Comment: Why Split and not Replace? What if the character isn't in the A-Z range?

Comment: Just a preference, this way is quick to write and serves the purpose. Replace will work too.

Comment: Thanks @Akash Shrivastava, You are my Hero. :P

Comment: @Oren Be aware that Akash's answer doesn't handle anything that isn't in the uppercase alpha range. I recommend changing the expression to `.#.` so that you catch any character either side of the `#`.

Answer (score 1):

The simple way, you can do:

1. `pos = <yourStringVariable>.IndexOf('#')` -> find '#' position
2. `target = yourStringVariable.Substring(pos - 1, 3)` -> get '#' and the next and previous one
3. `yourStringVariable.Replace(target, "")` -> clear them in string.